# Кастомизация консольного приложения в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, терминал

Пишу консольное приложение в Linux, вот и возникло два вопроса.

Во-первых, как программно развернуть эмулятор терминала на весь экран? Да, в Windows это делается с помощью Win API, но что делать, к примеру, в Ubuntu?

Во-вторых, как мне поменять фон в терминале во время исполнения программы? Чтобы у меня стояла не пользовательская тема, а предусмотренная мною?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ncurses в помощь

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а escape-последовательностей для этих целей нет случайно?

Comment: для этого нужно включить keypad

Comment: вот хорошая страчника по ncurses: http://www.linuxlib.ru/manpages/CURSES.3.shtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Linux нет понятия консольного приложения в смысле Windows.

Приложение может иметь управляющий терминал, с которым у него связаны дескрипторы стандартного ввода, вывода и вывода ошибок, и от которого могут приходить сигналы. Терминал может быть физическим или виртуальным, в последнем случае он может поддерживать или не поддерживать изменение количества строк и управление положением своего окна в графической среде (если оно вообще есть). И это зависит от программы эмулятора терминала, которых в Linux великое множество и укаждого свои возможности, однако те из них которые запускаются из X-Window, например xterm, обычно поддерживают набор команд VT102, в котором предусмотрено некоторое управление окном через [escape-последовательности (ищите dtterm)](http://www.xfree86.org/4.5.0/ctlseqs.html#VT100%20Mode), но обычно оно сокращено или отключено по-умолчанию или вовсе не реализовано. Включить у xterm его можно через X-ресурсы например при запуске эмулятора терминала:

```
xterm -xrm 'xterm*allowWindowOps: true'
```

Далее в открывшемся окне попробуйте:

```
$ printf '\033[3;0;0t' # переместить окно в верхний левый угол
$ printf '\033[9;1t' # во весь экран
```

Если определена переменная окружения `DISPLAY`, значит программа запущенна из X-Window, и вы можете запустить свой эмулятор терминала, указав в аргументах нужную конфигурацию и вашу программу в нём. По аргументам см. `man xterm`, `man gnome-terminal`, `man konsole` и т.п.